# Spring Integration TCP connection refused under multithreaded load/stress testing

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration project that handles TCP messages.

The simplest scenario is the PING message (receive msg from source and echo it back), the flow in the SI project is as follows :

1) Message is received from source (by a tcp-inbound-gateway). The source closes the socket after each message.

2) A transformer analyzes the message and sets (among others) a header value with the reply channel name

3) A Header-Value-Router is applied over the message that routes it back to the source.

**XML config (simplified version) is below :**

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="TCP_SRV"
                               type="server"
                               port="${router.port}"
                               using-nio="true"
                               single-use="true"
                               serializer="CustomSerializer"
                               deserializer="CustomSerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway request-channel="rawInputFromSource"
                            reply-channel="outputBackToSource"
                            connection-factory="TCP_SRV"/>

<int:channel id="rawInputFromSource"/>

<int:transformer ref="inputFromSourceTransformer"
                 input-channel="rawInputFromSource"
                 output-channel="processedInputFromSource"/>

<int:channel id="processedInputFromSource"/>

<bean id="inputFromSourceTransformer" class="my.org.InputFromSourceTransformer"/>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="processedInputFromSource" 
                         header-name="RouteToChannel"/>
```

It works ok from a functional pov when invoking messages manually, but it fails under stress testing. Once I ramp up over 15 threads (each thread running a for loop sending 10 messages) I receive **java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect** for about 20% of the attempts.

**The code snippets used by the threads to send the msg :**

```
byte[] sendAndReceive(byte[] data){
    byte[] result = new byte[data.length];
    try {
        Socket socket=new Socket("localhost", SI_PORT); // here is where the err occurs
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream  input = socket.getInputStream();
        output.write(data);
        input.read(result);
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Error :**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at my.org.PerformanceTest.sendAndReceive(PerformanceTest.java:98)
```

The requirements say it must pass with 60 threads. Any ideas what I can do to solve this issue ? I tried adding a **task:executor id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-10" queue-capacity="100" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"** on the factory but this didn't solved the issue.

Any advice is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the backlog on the server connection factory.

```
/**
 * The number of sockets in the connection backlog. Default 5;
 * increase if you expect high connection rates.
 * @param backlog The backlog to set.
 */
public void setBacklog(int backlog) {
    Assert.isTrue(backlog >= 0, "You cannot set backlog negative");
    this.backlog = backlog;
}
```

Available in XML configuration with the `backlog` attribute...

```
<xsd:attribute name="backlog" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Specifies the connection backlog for server sockets. Does not
            apply to client factories.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Highly recommend to add the "increase if you expect high connection rates" to the backlog attribute description https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html . Thanks again.